# Where can I find a full list of data accessible to facebook developers?

Tags: facebook

Is there any info to be found on what data does facebook store on users and what data can be accessed by their API?

edit:(a direct link so that I don't need to read through all SDKs and tutorials)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I believe is pretty direct link to facebook data tables, took me a while to find it, so maybe in the future someone will find it helpful. In order to view different tables scroll a bit down and click on blue links - each one of them is a different data set.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's developer documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: I know where documentation is. But I cannot find there a list of all accessible data...

Comment: Use the API documentation doesn't directly answer my question - I was counting more on a direct link to where the tables with data accessible to developers are.